# Fill two columns in SQL table as a result of an operation done on another (third) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, calculated-columns, fill

I have a time shift column in my `tblCalendar` table called `TimeShift` and need to fill two other columns in the same table, both columns have `Null` values and their names are `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

This serves as an example:

| TimeShift | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00AM - 4:00PM | Null | Null |
| 10:00AM - 6:00PM | Null | Null |
| 11:00AM - 7:00PM | Null | Null |

I need to fill the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns by doing a split on the first column.

I figured out how to use SQL functions to split the first column on '-' char.

But I didn't find a way to fill the Null columns with these extracted split data.

The query I found is:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(TimeShift, CHARINDEX('-', TimeShift) - 2) AS StartTime, 
    RIGHT(TimeShift, LEN(TimeShift) - CHARINDEX('-', TimeShift) -1) AS EndTime 
FROM
    tblCalendar
```

which will return the required data, but my question is: how to fill these values into the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns in my original table?

Many thanks

Comment: Done, MS SQL Server

Comment: I know you already marked this answered but it seems like you might want those columns to be computed using your logic and furthermore cast to the correct data type.

Comment: Thanks for your add, actually I'm using string types for all columns so no issue in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously, you'll need an `UPDATE` statement to update an existing table - and you can basically use the two expressions from your `SELECT` query.

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblCalendar
SET StartTime = LEFT(TimeShift, CHARINDEX('-', TimeShift) - 2), 
    EndTime = RIGHT(TimeShift, LEN(TimeShift) - CHARINDEX('-', TimeShift) -1) 
WHERE
    StartTime IS NULL AND EndTime IS NULL;
```

Depending on the datatypes of your columns, this might not work right away - maybe you also need to do some conversions from e.g. `VARCHAR` to `TIME` ....

Comment: Thanks a lot marc_s for your answer. You saved my Day! I was missing to use the last Where statement which solved the issue directly. Many Many Thanks